# Gps Tracking Issue

Tags: android, gps

In my application to do a GPS tracking.how to draw a driving direction for one source to destination. it's possible without using google navigation url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is possible but:

1. In any case, you need a "routing engine". A possible example is the Open Source Routing Machine: http://project-osrm.org/ .
2. You cannot use Google Maps with the routing service of another provider (both for technical and legal reasons). In this case, you should use the whole software stack supplied by, for example, the OpenStreetMap project: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use Google's solutions? I'm running [Google Tracks API](http://blog.jammer-store.com/2012/11/google-is-proud-to-present-two-new-ways-of-geolocation-and-tracking/) for a while and it gives me no problem.